# SilverStripe return URLSegment from SiteTree relation

Tags: php, silverstripe

So I have this:

```
private static $has_one = array(
    'ButtonLink' => 'SiteTree'
);
```

and this field

```
$fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Main', TreeDropdownField::create("ButtonLink", "Page link", "SiteTree"));
```

So that users can link this DataObject to a page from SiteTree. On the front-end I'm trying to return the `URLSegment` as:

```
$ButtonLink.Link
```

But it doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found it. You need to append *ID* to the field identifier because that's the db column name where the foreign record reference key is saved (SiteTree).

```
$fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Main', TreeDropdownField::create("ButtonLinkID", "Page link", "SiteTree"));
```